Transfer a vector graphic from Inkscape to photoshop
Can a vector graphic be transferred from Inkscape to Photoshop simply by using the copy-and-paste function?
thanks,
Saeed

Photoshop pastes nothing from the clipboard if the clipboard content is taken from Inkscape. If you paste the content at first to Affinity Designer, copy it again there and paste to Photoshop you'll get a vector smart object layer. Photoshop shows it, you can scale and rotate it. You cannot edit it with Photoshop's vector tools. But Photoshop lets you open it in a vector editor. The problem is old. The direct way from Inkscape to Adobe programs vanished about 15 years ago. Here's another workaround: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/144860/import-svg-as-shape-path-in-photoshop

No. Better to save as an SVG, and then place the SVG as a smart object in Photoshop.
